# Call method for objects of derived type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have some type hierarchy :

```
class GameObject{...};
class Subject:public GameObject{...};
class Player:public Subject{...};
class Bullet:public Subject{...};
class Enemy:public Subject{...};
```

In traversing the array of GameObject*, I check the condition and call method foo(*object1, *object2) ( object1 is reference to Bullet, object2 is reference to Player).

```
std::vector<GameObject*> objects;
// fill array ( pointers to Bullet, Enemy, Player)
foreach(auto obj1 : objects)
{
  foreach(auto obj2 : objects)
  {
     if(obj1.getID() != obj2.getID()
     {
        foo(*obj1, *obj2); 
     }
  }
}
```

Also I write some overloaded foo methods :

```
void foo(GameObject&, GameObject&)
void foo(Bullet&, Player&)
void foo(Bullet&, Enemy&)
```

But only foo(GameObject&, GameObject&) is called. Why?

Comment: Because the pointers are still of type `GameObject`. That's not how polymorphism works.

Comment: If you want to interpret the object as the derived type you have to `dynamic_cast` the base class pointer down to a pointer of the derived class.  (But of course you must know which derived type to use when casting each object, which sort of defeats the purpose of polymorphism.)

Answer (score 0):

These are pointers to `GameObject`. You dereference them and get objects of type `GameObject`, and this makes sense. If you dereferenced a pointer to `int` and got an object of type `Apple`, that'd be very odd.

`GameObject *` (a *pointer* to `GameObject`) means that there exists some piece of memory that this pointer points to, and this memory should be treated as an object of type `GameObject`. When you dereference a pointer, you actually get *access* to that memory, which is obviously treated as `GameObject`.

Comment: but the OP said objects are allocated through different derived class, can you explain more?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the objects are created.  The only thing that matters is that they are accessed through the `GameObject` interface, therefore they behave as `GameObject`s.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez, it doesn't matter: you dereference a pointer to `GameObject` and you get an object of type `GameObject`.

Comment: @ForceBru okay i get it now, when i tested Derived *d = new Derived() it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` overload to be called is chosen during program compilation. And compiler obviously has no idea what are the real types of objects that you pass in your loops so it chooses the only thing it knows for sure.

There are various ways to workaround this problem in general, google "double dispatch" or "visitor pattern".